# Получить активность жесткого диска через DeviceIOControl (WinAPI)

Tags: c#, winapi, io, hdd, device

Мне нужно отображать файловую активность ввода/вывода диска в своем приложении. Отсюда вопрос.
Из чего складывается показатель активности диска (активное время) как в Диспетчере задач?
Знаю что эти данные берутся из структуры `DISK_PERFORMANCE` в `DeviceIoControl`, но в документации мне не ясно, откуда и как вычислить этот показатель.
Чтобы было более понятно о чем я, прикладываю скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#r "System.Management"
using System.Management;
char driveLetter = 'C';
var path = $"Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name='0 {driveLetter}:'";
var wmiObj = new ManagementObject(path);
wmiObj.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>()
   .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(a => WriteLine($"{a.Key}\t{a.Value}"));
```

Мой вывод:

```
AvgDiskBytesPerRead     0
AvgDiskBytesPerTransfer 161280
AvgDiskBytesPerWrite    161280
AvgDiskQueueLength      0
AvgDiskReadQueueLength  0
AvgDisksecPerRead       0
AvgDisksecPerTransfer   0
AvgDisksecPerWrite      0
AvgDiskWriteQueueLength 0
Caption 
CurrentDiskQueueLength  0
Description 
DiskBytesPersec         646075
DiskReadBytesPersec     0
DiskReadsPersec         0
DiskTransfersPersec     4
DiskWriteBytesPersec    646075
DiskWritesPersec        4
Frequency_Object    
Frequency_PerfTime  
Frequency_Sys100NS  
Name    0               C:
PercentDiskReadTime     0
PercentDiskTime         1
PercentDiskWriteTime    1
PercentIdleTime         98
SplitIOPerSec           0
Timestamp_Object    
Timestamp_PerfTime  
Timestamp_Sys100NS
```

Нужный вам параметр: `PercentDiskTime`

Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977903/how-can-we-get-disk-performance-info-in-c-sharp

Comment: Спасибо. Через WMI я знаю как получить. Мне нужно именно через WinAPI. Я уже нашел готовую библиотеку-обертку над DeviceIoControl. Мне просто не понятно как рассчитывается нужный показатель. В этой библиотеке точно такие же свойства как в доках. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-disk_performance?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Таких WinAPI функций НЕТ!!!!!!!, т.к. это счётчики производительности, и в них нет такой хорошей обратной совместимости как в WinAPI, а так-же они могу меняться чуть ли не с каждой версией винды. Нужно обращаться напрямую к WMI'йным DLL. Пример данных для ответа тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394262(v=vs.85) и тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394308(v=vs.85) так-же можете воспользоваться WMI-nuget пакетами, но не факт что они в свою очередь не используют ManagementObject. WmiLight, есть на github, напрямую с wmi-dll общается, но какой смысл...

Comment: @Mr.Evgen PS откройте свой диспетчер задач и посмотрите какие dll он использует, скорее всего те-же wmi*.dll

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. Почему-то всегда думалось, что WMI дергает данные из WinAPI и просто отдает в удобоваримом виде. С WMI не хотелось бы связываться опять т. к. на мой взгляд этот интерфейс слишком "тормознутый" для моих задать. Я раньше как раз и использовал WMI, а сейчас перешел на WinAPI и выполнение ускорилось на порядок. А вот счетчика производительности не хватает.

Comment: @Mr.Evgen он и дёргает данные оттуда, но не в таком виде, он делает это по принципу: как измерить скорость? нужно узнать разницу в расстоянии между 2мя координатами и поделить на время...

Comment: WMI делает два WinAPI запроса в разные моменты времени, получая текущий момент времени, счётчик прочитанных/записанных байт, на основании этого считает разницу во времени и дельту байт, высчитывает скорость, дополнительно накручивая ещё сложной логики сверху, например поднимая характеристику интерфейса (IDE/SATA2/SATA3/NVME) и текущей длины очередей записи/чтения (для обычного HDD макс длина очереди = 32), и на основании этого выплёвывает попугая в % = текущий/long.max... Для WinAPI это слишком много наворотов, причём ненадёжных, а для счётчика производительности - самое то.

Comment: Тут ещё есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253154/get-current-cpu-ram-and-disk-drive-usage-in-c-sharp с использованием PerformanceCounter(System.Diagnostics), может он сам считает в обход WMI на основе WinAPI (нужно уточнять в исходниках .NET)

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение. Теперь все понял.

Comment: Да. Тоже сейчас наткнулся на PerfomanceCounter. Буду смотреть его.

Comment: Если же вам нужен непосредственно свой счётчик на коленке, то тут описание WinAPI функции DeviceIoControl: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/calling-deviceiocontrol и структуры: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol А тут пример использования как получить общее число I/O байт https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450157/how-to-get-global-windows-i-o-statistics  DeviceIoControl(dev, IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE, NULL, 0, &disk_info, sizeof(disk_info), &bytes, NULL) Так-же через эту функцию можно получить инфо о диске и посчитать %.

Comment: И за это тоже огромное спасибо!